# How can I check for a record before creating it in my seeds file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

My Rails seeds file looks like the following...

```
  Club.create([
       {name: 'Atlanta Falcons', moniker: 'Falcons', city: 'Atlanta', state: 'GA', zipcode: '0', code: 'ATL', conference: 'NFC', division: 'South', primary_color: 'BD0D18', secondary_color: '000000', tertiary_color: 'FFFFFF', quaternary_color: 'DCE0E5', quinary_color: '', weather_location: 'Atlanta+GA+USGA0028:1:US', plays_in_dome: '1', time_zone: 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)', logo_image: 'atl.gif', word_art_image: 'title.gif', club_key: '4909', stadium_name: 'Georgia Dome', mini_image: 'atl.png'},
       {name: 'Buffalo Bills', moniker: 'Bills', city: 'Buffalo', state: 'NY', zipcode: '0', code: 'BUF', conference: 'AFC', division: 'East', primary_color: '00338D', secondary_color: 'C60C30', tertiary_color: 'FFFFFF', quaternary_color: '', quinary_color: '', weather_location: 'Buffalo+NY+USNY0181:1:US', plays_in_dome: '0', time_zone: 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)', logo_image: 'buf.gif', word_art_image: 'bil_ltyp_blu_pms.png', club_key: '4910', stadium_name: 'Ralph Wilson Stadium', mini_image: 'buf.png'}
    )]
```

How can i do this with an array of hashes and still check for records and not create them if they already exist so I avoid duplicates?  I was just going to allow the validations to throw out the duplicates; however, it didn't seem correct. Thanks!

Comment: You must use find_or_create_by method.. I'm on mobile..so not able to give you the link.. Search it.. :-)http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#find-or-create-by

Comment: if you run seeds before create any record, use first_or_create method.
`Club.where(name: "Atlanta Falcons").first_or_create` or `first_or_initialize`
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_initialize

Comment: How would I use first_or_create while still using one create method with many hashes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is too big to fit into a comment, there you have it as an answer:

```
rows = [
   {name: 'Atlanta Falcons', moniker: 'Falcons', city: 'Atlanta', state: 'GA', zipcode: '0', code: 'ATL', conference: 'NFC', division: 'South', primary_color: 'BD0D18', secondary_color: '000000', tertiary_color: 'FFFFFF', quaternary_color: 'DCE0E5', quinary_color: '', weather_location: 'Atlanta+GA+USGA0028:1:US', plays_in_dome: '1', time_zone: 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)', logo_image: 'atl.gif', word_art_image: 'title.gif', club_key: '4909', stadium_name: 'Georgia Dome', mini_image: 'atl.png'},
   {name: 'Buffalo Bills', moniker: 'Bills', city: 'Buffalo', state: 'NY', zipcode: '0', code: 'BUF', conference: 'AFC', division: 'East', primary_color: '00338D', secondary_color: 'C60C30', tertiary_color: 'FFFFFF', quaternary_color: '', quinary_color: '', weather_location: 'Buffalo+NY+USNY0181:1:US', plays_in_dome: '0', time_zone: 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)', logo_image: 'buf.gif', word_art_image: 'bil_ltyp_blu_pms.png', club_key: '4910', stadium_name: 'Ralph Wilson Stadium', mini_image: 'buf.png'}
]

rows.each do |row|
  Club.where(club_key: row[:club_key]).first_or_create(row)
end
```

So for each row, if that row exists, will just return the record from the database otherwise it will create it.

You can find more about [first_or_create](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create)

```
# File activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb, line 149
def first_or_create(attributes = nil, &block) # :nodoc:
  first || create(attributes, &block)
end
```

If you don't want to use first_or_create you can check for the existence of an object using [exists?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-exists-3F) like this:

```
rows.each do |row|
  unless Club.exists?(club_key: code[:club_key])
    Club.create(row)
  end 
end
```

but, since this is more verbose, you should stick with first_or_create to be more concise. I added this just to present an alternative.

Comment: Doh! thanks so much! Didn't think about doing it with an each like that.